# Where is the golang code to auto parse time.Time from json strings?

Tags: json, go

For years when I saw json like:

```
{"timestamp": "2022-06-16T05:37:34.483Z"}
```

I would make my golang struct like:

```
type Foo struct {
  Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
}
```

But then someone showed me that:

```
type Foo struct {
  Timestamp time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
}
```

Will just magically parse it from that string into the `time.Time` thing I want!

My question is, where inside golang source is this done? What formats does it parse? Do other strings from json get "magically" parsed too? Could I define my own?

i.e. with json

```
{"foo": "my_own_format"}
```

```
type Foo struct {
  Foo Bar `json:"foo"`
}

type Bar struct {
   Words []string
}
```

Could I make the end result of this json.Unmarshal calling strings.Split("my_own_format", "_") and getting that Bar struct's Words to have "my", "own", "format" in its Words array?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.UnmarshalJSON

Comment: See also https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler and https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal

Comment: It's down voted because people feel this is a RTFM too easy to post question. But thank you to those that gave me these links! So can I just define (b *Bar) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error { // do strings split logic } ? Amazing!

Comment: As community we should never assume that something is so easy that its not worth to be posted. Not everyone has the same level of understanding. Which is kinda the purpose of StackOverFlow anyway.  :-)

Comment: @MadDogTannen (and the OP), the question gets downvoted becase it's clearly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): it fails under that «Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource» rule amoung the list of prohibited types of questions. Well, it actually contains two questions in one, which is another reason ;-)